# Populate/insert values in query

Tags: c, string, replace, sqlite, str-replace

I'm new with C, i'm trying to make simple program with sqlite3 db.

I have query like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) "  \
     "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California' ); " \
```

I have values in char* variables, is it possible to use %s like on printf for example:

```
sql = somefunction("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) "  \
     "VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, '%s');", 1, 'Paul', 32, 'California');
```

If that is not possible what is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `'Paul'` and `'California'`  -> `"Paul"` and `"California"` you mean?

Comment: also, what do you mean by _possible_? what is the purpose of the `somefunction()`?

Comment: to print to a _string_, `sprintf()` might come handy, if you need so.

Comment: Yes I mean "Paul" and "California" i have that values in variables. somefunction() - is there any function that can replace %s with given values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) looks appropriate for your problem (introduced in C89).

Now simply do something like this:

```
sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) "
"VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, '%s');", 1, "Paul", 32, "California");
```

To prevent a buffer overflow, use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) (introduced in C99).

Answer (score 1):

```
     Create a buffer and fill it with the string using sprintf.
     Here's a very generic example:

     int main ()
     {
       char buffer [50];
       int n, a=5, b=3;
       n=sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);
       printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n",buffer,n);
       return 0;
     }

     Output: 
     [5 plus 3 is 8] is a string 13 chars long
```